Gerchberg-Saxton algorithm noisy phase retrieval
I am trying to reconstruct a phase-only diffraction grating that produces $n$ beams of equal intensity.
Specifically, I am trying to reconstruct a 9-beam phase profile with the following form:
$$ \phi(x) = \sum a_m \cos(2\pi m x/P),$$
where $P$ is the period. I have been given the correct coefficients up through $m=7$ and $P=432 \mu m$, and I have confirmed in simulation that this does actually produce 9 equal beams for a $1.064 \mu m$ input beam. I want to know how to obtain the phase profile.
According to the Gerchberg Saxton algorithm, I need to

Define the target image amplitude and start with a phase of 1.

Inverse FFT to the near-field and force the resulting amplitude to 1

FFT to the far-field and force the resulting amplitude to the target image

Repeat


In MATLAB it looks like this
numRuns = 1000;
ff = fftshift(exp(1i));
for n = 1:numRuns
    ff = target.*exp(1i*angle(ff));
    nf = ifft(ff);
    nf = exp(1i*angle(nf));
    ff = fft(nf);
end

First, I reduced the problem to 1D since I want a linear array. I have my target image of ~45000 pixels (the way I defined the beam spacing and diameters correlates to $1\mu m$ per pixel):

But my propagated near-field and phase look like


Several issues and questions

The phase looks like white noise and is not periodic. The output beams are speckled. There is gain.

Where does the GS algorithm take wavelength taken into account?

How does the target image resolution affect the FFT. Is 0 padding needed?

Can I simplify the problem by just putting delta functions where I want the beam spots?



The reconstruction is not deterministic and there always will be noise, the ordinary Gerchberg-Saxton tends to be especially prone to (high frequency) noise. There definitely is literature on that.
The wavelength enters in the propagation of the fields between image and object plane and therefore is implicitly also relevant for the resolution you obtain in frequency space - but this is all relative and also depends on the propagation distance, see eg. free space propagation using the Fresnel kernel.  For the resolution between of the two spaces, the usual Fourier transform relations hold.

While just using the FFT function certainly is easier and tempting, I don't think this is the best way to approach this problem. Instead, you should implement the propagation manually using the Fresnel kernel for free space propagation.
If you need to include information about the wavelength, this is the way to go. Technically, it may be possible to obtain the same result by rescaling your frequency space coordinates to match the wavelength, but I am not certain what subtleties this would entail.
